# Is there a more convenient method for converting a base to be orthogonal than Gram Schmidt?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

I find performing the Gram-Schmidt method a little cumbersome and confusing (easy to make mistakes along the way)

Maybe I just need to practice it more, but are there other more convenient methods which I could use? Or alternatively are there any tricks which could make actually performing it easier?

Comment: There are Householder reflections and Givens rotations, but they are even more cumbersome and confusing to perform by hand.

Comment: @Rahul, Good to know, thanks :)

Comment: Since you need to be able to do this on an exam, practice this a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an algorithm fairly well suited to computer-based implementation, and generally a pain in the neck to do by hand.

On the other hand, if you write your basis (assuming we're talking about $\Bbb R^n$ here for the moment) as the columns of a matrix, then doing a little column reduction can make your job easier, with fewer square roots. For instance, if we start with 
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 }
$$
then GS involves a $\sqrt{5}$ to normalize the first vector, and that persists in the computations with the second vector. But if we add the second vector to the first, we get 
$$
\pmatrix{3 & 2 \\
4 & 2 }
$$
and because $3^2 + 4^2  = 5^2$, the normalization of the first column is really easy: it becomes

$$
\pmatrix{\frac{3}{5} & 2 \\
\frac{4}{5} & 2 }.
$$

But the fact is that opportunities like these don't present themselves very often, and it's seldom worth looking for them. On the other hand, doing a bit of "column reduction" to make as many entries zero as possible...that's generally a way to reduce the number of places where you can make numerical/algebraic mistakes while carrying out he rest of G-S.

Following up on @Gimusi's answer:

A typical "step" in G-S consists of having a set (possibly empty) of orthonormal vectors $u_1, \ldots, u_k$ and a set $\{v_{k+1}, \ldots, v_p\}$ that you want to move into the $u$-set. You do this a vector at a time. Letting $v$ denote $v_{k+1}$, you typically do this as follows:

1. for $i = 1, \ldots k$, make $v$ orthogonal to $u_i$ by replacing $v$ with 
   $$
   v' = v - (v \cdot u_i) u_i.
   $$
   When you do that, you have $(v' \cdot u_i) = (v \cdot u_i) - (v \cdot u_i) (u_i \cdot u_i)$, and because the $u_i$ are all unit vectors, the last factor is $1$, so $v'$ ends up orthogonal to $u_i$.
2. Once you've made $v$ orthogonal to all the $u_i$s, replace $v$ with 
   $$
   v' = \frac{1}{\|v\|} v,
   $$
   a process called "normalizing" it, and let $u_{k+1} $ be this new, unit length $v$ (and delete $v_{k+1}$ from the $v$-set.

Repeat until done.

At each stage, the $u$-set consists of orthogonal **unit** vectors.

In the alternative version, you simply make the $u$s orthogonal to one another, but *not* necessarily unit vectors. You then follow this process:

1. for $i = 1, \ldots k$, make $v$ orthogonal to $u_i$ by replacing $v$ with 
   $$
   v' = v - \frac{v \cdot u_i}{u_i \cdot u_i} u_i.
   $$
   When you do that, you have 
   \begin{align}
   (v' \cdot u_i) 
   &= (v \cdot u_i) - \frac{v \cdot u_i}{u_i \cdot u_i} (u_i \cdot u_i)\\
   &= (v \cdot u_i) - v \cdot u_i\\
   & = 0
   \end{align}
   so that $v'$ is now orthogonal to $u_i$.
2. Once you've made $v$ orthogonal to all the $u_i$s, let $u_{k+1} $ be this new, unit length $v$ (and delete $v_{k+1}$ from the $v$-set.

Finally, when the $v$-set is empty and the $u$-set is full, normalize each vector in the $u$-set (i.e., divide it by its own length).

Notice that until this last step, there's never a square root in sight!

Comment: Thanks, these are nice tips :)

Comment: And yea, I wish I could leave to the computer :P but some of my exam questions require me to find an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't understand why you added the division by $u_i \cdot u_i$  but I see what you meant now. Thanks for the in depth answer!

Answer (score 2):

To facilitate the calculation by GS  you can

- try at first to find at least 2 or 3 orthogonal vectors by inspection (usually this is not difficult)
- for the others perform GS letting the normalization at the end of the
  process

Comment: Finding 2 or 3 orthogonal vectors is indeed a good trick, and tends to work well on exams. (Indeed, just swapping the order of the basis elements so that there's minimal work up front is good. As for "normalize late", you have to remember to change each vector $v$ to $v - \frac{(v \cdot u)}{u \cdot u} u$ (where $u$ is a previously-processed vector) i.e., the include the **denominator** in the coefficient for the subtracted prior vectors.

Comment: Thanks also good tips! @Jhon Hughes, Im not sure what you meant about the normalization.

Comment: See my additional comments in my own answer.